# how do I use an array to create a CSV file and download it (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv, export-to-csv

Below I have a mix of current code that i found on a separate question on here But i am getting an error saying that the rowArray

```
function downloadcsv(){
    const rows = [];

        for(var i = 0; i < vm.data.length; ++i)
        {
            rows.push(vm.data[i].value, vm.data[i].count);
        }
        console.log(rows);

        let csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";

        rows.forEach(function(rowArray){

            //i get a rowArray.join is not a function error when i run this. 
           //What can i do to fix this?

            let row = rowArray.join(",");
            csvContent += row + "\r\n";
        });

        var encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
        window.open(encodedUri);
    }
```

I thank you guys in advance.

Comment: What are you expecting `rows.push` to be doing? You are calling `join` on a string at the moment because your use of `push` is creating one large array of strings.

From your implementation I think you're expecting it to be an array of arrays. If you want an array of arrays you should be calling `rows.push([vm.data[i].value, vm.data[i].count])`.

Comment: @NickRamsbottom vm.data is currently an array with objects. How do i turn that into a CSV file and download it?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a blob url with a blob from your csv string like this:

```
var csvData = new Blob([csvContent], {type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;'});
var csvURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(csvData);
window.open(csvURL);
```

So in your example it will be

```js
function downloadcsv() {
  const rows = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < vm.data.length; ++i) {
    rows.push(vm.data[i].value, vm.data[i].count);
  }
  console.log(rows);

  let csvContent = "";
  rows.forEach(function(rowArray) {

    //i get a rowArray.join is not a function error when i run this. 
    //What can i do to fix this?

    let row = rowArray.join(",");
    csvContent += row + "\r\n";
  });

  var csvData = new Blob(csvContent, {type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;'});
  var csvURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(csvData);
  window.open(encodedUri);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting the error 'rowArray.join is not a function' is because you are calling it on a type that is not an array. This is because the push function is making one large array of strings instead of an array of arrays like you are expecting. I have pasted a way of fixing it below:

```
const vmData = [
  {
    value: 'first',
    count: 12,
  },
  {
    value: 'second',
    count: 100,
  },
  {
    value: 'third',
    count: 20,
  },
  {
    value: 'fourth',
    count: 30,
  },
];


const makeCSV = (data) => {
  const rows = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    rows.push(`${data[i].value},${data[i].count}`);
  }

  return rows.join('\n');
};


const csv = makeCSV(vmData);
```

You could make this more elegant using `array.map()` but it does the job.